# Surface spanning a closed curve?

Tags: terminology

This a question about math terminology - What is the meaning of "a surface $S$ spanning a closed curve $\Gamma$"? I am not looking for a technical definition, just a visual understanding is enough.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that that the boundary of the surface $S$ is $\Gamma.$

Comment: OK. Thanks a lot, that's what I thought.